# How to avoid websites detect and block webscraping after a while?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to webscrape information from amazon which works fine at the beginning. But after doing it multiple times in periodic time frames it stopped working because the website suspects that I am a bot.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, re, csv, datetime, time, threading, random, schedule

urls = ['insert pages here']

headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36',
    }

def getStock():
    for url in urls:
        response = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        div = soup.find(id="availability")
        print(div)
        time.sleep(1)

getStock()
```

At the beginning I get wished results like this:

```html
<div class="a-section a-spacing-base" id="availability">
<span class="a-size-medium a-color-success">

            Only 13 left in stock.



    </span>
</div>
```

But after a few times it returns only `none` even if I didn't change the urls or anything within the code. The website simply blocked or redirected my requests.

How can I adapt my code to avoid getting blocked by the website?

Answer (score 1):

Website can block you, for example if you wget a website too quikly

Comment: Could you specify on which sources your answer builds on?

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of things in a simple HTTP request. When the server detects an IP is making way too many requests and it is probably not a human then he can block you. There's methods for avoiding that like having your IP changed, random `user-agent`, etc.